# Sudoers can't prevent commands from executing from bash shell script

Tags: sudoers

I want to prevent users using "`sudo rm`" form anywhere.
I have edited `sudoers`:

## Members of the admin group may gain root privileges

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL,!/bin/rm
```

And ok：

```
derek@derek-desktop:~$ sudo rm

Sorry, user derek is not allowed to execute '/bin/rm' as root on derek-desktop.
```

But I create a test.sh with a rm command

```
derek@derek-desktop:~$ cat test.sh
rm --help
```

It show me the rm help.
Seems `sudoers` can't prevent this behavior. I want to disable all the users running rm from `sudo`.
 Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you have added to the sudoers works fine. It prevents users in the `admin` group from running `sudo rm` anywhere on the server. However, it doesn't stop them from running `rm`

If you change test.sh to have `sudo rm --help` this **will** error.

If you don't trust a user to run the rm command maybe you could create an if statement in the global bash.bashrc such as....

```
group=`groups`
if [[ $group == *admin* ]] ; then
        alias rm=''
        alias unalias=''
fi
```

Hope this offers a somewhat alternative to your question.